# How to get applicationId of Spark application deployed to YARN in Java?

Tags: apache-spark

In the case of Scala, we can use `SparkContext.applicationId` but I was not able to find any way to do the same using Spark's java API.

Using `SparkConf.getAppId()` results in NoSuchElementException: spark.app.id

Is there any other unique Id that can be used?

My use case: I want the Spark job to not fail in case output from the previous job already exist and want to avoid deleting the output of previous job and avoid using random UUID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SparkContext.applicationId`:

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = ...;
jsc.sc.applicationId;
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to get the retry count as well? I guess applicationId will be same in case of retry

Comment: When you have application id you can use REST API (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) but I don't know if there is any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Java code

```
System.out.println("appid = " + spark.sparkContext().applicationId());
```

Result

```
appid = app-20171023065927-0026
```